# Nest JavaScript Code inside another JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested

I am trying to make an input field in HTML be added dynamically when a user clicks the plus sign. Also, my input field in turn is comprised of three fields which, when entered (`maxlength` are 2, 10 and 3 in three fields), and when the `maxlength` is reached, auto-tab to next field.

Now, during this, I used a `moveCursor` function included in HTML input and defined in JavaScript. Now, after auto-tabbing, I need to create the function where it adds the input field.

To do that, I used the following JavaScript logic which triggers upon clicking the plus sign (not working).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" onkeyup="moveCursor(this,'txt2') class="txt1" maxlength="2" style=" width: 10%; float:left"name="mytext[]" maxlength="10" placeholder="XX"/><input type="text" onkeyup="moveCursor(this,'txt3') maxlength="3" class="txt2" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX"style="width: 20%; float: left"name="mytext[]"/><input type="text" placeholder="XXX"style="width: 10%"name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Here in the logic I have entered the HTML code, along with the `moveCursor` function which auto-tabs it, but now its not running since it is nested in JavaScript. However, both this function and `moveCursor` function are defined in the same file.

The `moveCursor` function which auto-tabs the fields(working) is as follows:

```
function moveCursor(from, to) {
  var length = from.value.length;
  var maxlength = from.getAttribute("maxlength");
  if (length == maxlength) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("." + to).focus();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `$(wrapper).append(..)` line contains syntax errors. You need to escape the single-quotes that are nested inside the string literal because the string literal is itself quoted with single quotes.

Comment: Also you have already used jquery to select your elements when you store them in vars, no need to do it again with $(add_button)

Comment: But how do i execute the movecursor function inside append there, will it work? The moveCursor function for auto tabbing is in the same file as jquery one. That's like nesting javascript function inside html, and appending the whole in another javascript function.